# Redirect multiple subdomains to different directories

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, seo

I am in the process of migrating my site to a different domain. The old domain contains multiple subdomains that I want to be redirected to the new domain as directories.

Is it possible to pull off something like this in .htaccess?

To my understanding, these directives will redirect a specific subdomain to another URL:

```
RewriteEngine On
    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/url-1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
```

My question is, what would it look like if there were multiple subdomains going to different URL folders?

Edit:
What other parameters should I include if I wanted to redirect all the contents (pages and subdirectories) of a specific subdomain to a new URL?

Comment: Assuming that the name of the directory and the name of the subdomain are independent the answer is: you implement one such combination of condition and rule per subdomain.

Comment: Thanks, that means my script will have multiple lines of this correct? @arkascha

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain1.example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/url-1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NC,L,QSA]

Comment: That is what I suggested, correct, one such combination per subdomain. Though you can just `^` as matching pattern in the rule, since you are not interested in what is captured anyway. Also the `NC` flag does not make any sense here.

Comment: Are there any other parameters that I should add if let's say I'd like to redirect all the contents (subdirectories included) of a subdomain to a new URL?

Comment: I think you are tackling this from the wrong angle. You invest too much into could, might, options, flags ... Stop that. Things don't get better just because you add things. Just go. Implement your rules. Keep them simple and use them. Test them. _Then_ , if something does _not_ work as you expect, _then_ is the time to focus on that detail and enhance your implementation.